# regular expression change

Tags: java, regex

i'm not very good at regular expressions..

how would I add a ".tile" (without quotes) to this regular expression pattern:

```
private static final Pattern JSP_PathPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+\\/)(\\w+)(\\.(jsp|.?htm.?|.?xslt,.?xsl))$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4):

```
private static final Pattern JSP_PathPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+\\/)(\\w+)(\\.(jsp|.?htm.?|.?xslt,.?xsl|tile))$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

However, from my understanding of the code (checking file extensions), this Regex is flawed in a few ways:

- Extra, non-literal `.` (match *anything*, thus allowing things like `xhtmy`)
- Errant `,` for the `xlt`
- No need to for the filename check.

As such, I recommend the following expression:

```
private static final Pattern JSP_PathPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\.(jsp|html?|xslt?|tile))$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

To be fair, you don't need to use a Regex. You could string split on the `.` and test the last element.

Either way, I encourage you to [learn Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).